# Reclaim disk space in Bitcoin Core full node

Tags: bitcoin-core, storage-footprint

I have a few stacks: **full-node Bitcoin Core** + **Fulcrum**.
Because of Fulcrum, I have to use `txindex`, so it's not a pruning node.

The current disk size is **644 GiB** for all Bitcoin Core nodes.

Do you know how to reclaim some disk space? Is this even possible?